# My WiFi won't list any available SSID

Tags: release-freya, wifi

So after clean install of elementary OS freya and install some packages i got an issue with my WiFi connection.
it says disconnected and nothing shows up but i have many available WiFi in my place. And when i check my phone it was detecting all available WiFi connection but my notebook with freya in it just don't detect at all.

I've searching and googling any available solution but none of them are fixing my issue. I'm a noob at linux and i don't know what todo anymore :(

Please help me

Comment: What's your wifi card? Pci or usb? Vendor and model?

Answer (score 1):

A few things you could try:

- Try booting into an older version of the Linux kernel. This option will be available if you've installed updates to Freya. When you first boot your computer, the menu that appears should give you the option to boot into an older version.
- Try uninstalling the packages that you installed and then reboot.
- Open the terminal and run `ifconfig`. This command will list the network interfaces that are set up on your computer. If you paste the output of the command into your post, that might help with troubleshooting.

Just out of curiosity, what packages did you install?